# 14 Bootstrap 4.5 carousels on a single webpage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to **add 14 carousels** on a single webpage. I created all of them and they work, but behave unpredictably.

Here is the skeleton I use for all of them (with a unique ID for each of the carousels):

```
<div id="ch6-1-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="carousel-item-responsive item-16by9">
                <div class="content" style="background: url(img/ch6/s1-4.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="carousel-item-responsive item-16by9">
                <div class="content" style="background: url(img/ch6/s1-5.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="carousel-item-responsive item-16by9">
                <div class="content" style="background: url(img/ch6/s1-6.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The sliders which have `class="carousel slide"` start sliding correctly on the second round.
The first round they either move too slowly or too fast, or the photos change with no sliding, or they slide showing the section's background.

One of the sections has 2 carousels on it, but they are completely asynchronized.

Some sliders have `class="carousel slide carousel-fade"`, and those work okay.

Iэму checked every section for the matter of the missing opening/closing tags, but all the necessary tags are there.

What can be the problem there? What can I do to make them slide correctly and synchronized?

Comment: Have you tried adding images with `<img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">` instead of a div with a `style` attribute ?

Comment: Yes I did, it has the same effect. Another weird thing is that once I add the same picture as the image for each of the 4 slides in the carousel (or as a bg image for a div in the version with divs) it works perfectly. If I change the other 3 photos (no single symbol of the code, the name of the image file only) - it starts behaving weird.

Comment: I've found the root cause. The problem was in the image size - any time a picture was to be changed by a picture of other dimensions there was a weird behavior.

Comment: Of course, in carousel, you must have fixed sizes to avoid any unexpected behavior. You can respond to your question and mark it as the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the root cause. The problem was in the image size - any time a picture was to be changed by a picture of other dimensions there was a weird behavior.